# Google Analytics Custom Dimension not sending properly

Tags: google-analytics

I am setting up click tracking for a ticket management app. We have some custom dimensions we want to track, but it doesn't seem like some of them are coming through properly.

```
function fees(fee, userID) {
    const analyticsObject = {
      dimension1: userID, //<uuid>
      dimension2: fee.ticketNumber, //<int>
      dimension3: fee.selectedFee.consultantFee, //<int>
      dimension4: fee.selectedFee.price, //<int>
      dimension8: fee.selectedFee.name //<string>
    };
    sendEvent('event', 'Fee', 'click', analyticsObject);
  }
```

All of those dimensions are set properly in Google Analytics, but for whatever reason `dimension8` will not show up in any of the reports I do.

One particular reports drilldown for consultantFees is set up:

```
userID
- ticketNumber
- - feeName
- - - consultantFee
```

However, when I get to level 3, (feeName) nothing shows up, at all. I fear I'm just missing something somewhere, but this is also happening on another custom dimension.

```
function nxt(note, ticketNumber) {
    const analyticsObject = {
      dimension1: note.user._id,
      dimension2: ticketNumber,
      dimension7: note.body
    }
    sendEvent('event', 'NXT', 'click', analyticsObject);
  }
```

This report is set up:

```
userID
- ticketNumber
- - noteBody
```

Again, the third level shows nothing.

Comment: Are you able to see param in debug mode  ?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @vaquarkhan. I did check out the debug logs, but it miraculously started working soon after that, so I may not have waited long enough.